# Serve static favicon file in Compojure

Tags: clojure, compojure

According to [Compojure](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Compojure/Tutorials_and_Tips):

> Compojure does not serve static files by default, nor does it
>   automatically deal out 404s when no route matches.

So to deal with that, we have to set these [Public Vars](http://weavejester.github.io/compojure/compojure.route.html)

- files
- not-found
- resources

And this is how we currently set it:

```
(defroutes app-routes
  (route/files "/" {:root "path/to/public"})
  (route/resources "/")
  (route/not-found "Not Found"))
```

It worked as expected when most of the static files are accessed through the web browser.

e.g.

http://localhost:3000/img/icon.png

**But the problem is, it doesn't work on favicon files.**

e.g.

http://localhost:3000/img/favicon.ico

It treats this as a different call which it should be serve as a static file.

**Response to to the `CURL` I run:**

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 3000 (#0)
> GET /img/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: localhost:3000
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Tue, 28 Jul 2015 19:05:24 GMT
< Last-Modified: Thu, 28 May 2015 14:51:16 +0000
< Content-Length: 1106
< Content-Type: image/x-icon
* Server Jetty(7.6.13.v20130916) is not blacklisted
< Server: Jetty(7.6.13.v20130916)
```

Comment: Paste the response to a `curl -vvv http://localhost:3000/img/favicon.ico` please

Comment: @JamesSharp I have posted the response.

Comment: It seems ok... why do you say it doesn't work? If you are testing with a browser its cache may be messing up but it does have nothing to do with compojure. Have a [look](https://superuser.com/questions/375321/how-to-refresh-bookmark-favicons-in-chrome)

Comment: It loads the favicon but when I said it doesn't work I mean the `compojure` "I believe" didn't served it as a static file but instead it treats it like one of the `routes`. So it's like it fall under this route:  `(GET "/:slug" [* :as req slug] (search req slug))`

Answer (score 3):

`files`, `resources`, and `not-found` are functions, not variables that you set.  When you call `(route/files "/" {:root "path/to/public"})`, a route for resolving URLs under "/" as static files under "path/to/public" is returned.

`defroutes` defines a collection of routes.  These routes are tried in the order they are listed, until the first one that returns a response.

If you add a route `(GET "/:slug" [* :as req slug] (search req slug))` before the others, then any URL other than "/" will be handled by this new route — including the favicon request.  On the other hand, if you add it just before the `not-found` route, then it should work.

Also, if there isn't a static file that matches the request, then the `files` route will fail and the next one will be tried.  So you should also check that `favicon.ico` actually exists and is in the `img` sub-directory.

Comment: Thanks for making that clear. What's weird is that it does exist on the `img` directory but still being handled by `/:slug` route, while images within the same directory isn't.

Answer (score 0):

umm...

This works for me, (wherever you define/declare your routes):

In the namespace section:

```
            [ring.util.response :refer [resource-response]]
```

Down below (at least above (def app ):

```
(defn wrap-return-favicon [handler]
  (fn [req]
    (if (= [:get "/favicon.ico"] [(:request-method req) (:uri req)])
      (resource-response "favicon.ico" {:root "public/img"})
      (handler req))))
```

then in:

```
(def app
  (-> routes
      ...
      wrap-return-favicon
      wrap-stacktrace))
```